# self in multiprocessing python

Tags: python, class, methods, multiprocessing, self

I have searched for how to do this and I don't find it. I suppose someone will put me a link to a google search, but I really don't know what exactly to look for. I'm trying to use Multiprocessing in python with a method of a class. This method has the "self" arg, but even if I pass it I get an error saying that I don't provide it:

Code:

```
def move_one_particle(self, moving_way):

def move(self, moving_way):
    for dummy_time in range(self.num_particles):
        p=mp.Process(target=self.move_one_particle, args=(moving_way))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

output:

```
move_one_particle() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: I have also tried with args=(self,moving_way) and have the same output

Comment: Is this method part of a class?

Comment: yes, sorry! I thought I have expecified it

Comment: As written, I cannot reproduce this error.  Are you showing us exactly the code written?  (For instance, your `move_one_particle` function is a syntax error presently.)

Comment: Actually, I didn't write it exactly the same.  I did `target=move_one_particle, args=(self, moving_way)` and it worked.

Comment: It works without the multiprocessing. I only changed the move function, so the other must work.

Comment: The problem was that I put move_one_particle() instead of move_one_particle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a tuple thing. When you write

```
(moving_away)
```

it's not a tuple. However

```
(moving_away, )
```

is. See the [Python wiki on this point](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax).

---

Here is a mockup of your problem that works by me.

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self, baz):
        print baz

    def shmo(self):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.bar, args=(3,))
        p.run()

>> Foo().shmo()
3
```

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I missed that "feature"  That's ugly syntax, and an easy mistake to make.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Yeah, some people [don't like it](http://bugs.python.org/issue2817).

Comment: It seems like for consistency an empty tuple should be `(,)`, oh well.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Not sure I agree on the last point.

Comment: The problem was that i typed move_one_particle() and its withou brakets. The tuple thing give me an error after that fix, so thanks =)

Comment: For future Googlers, an empty tuple is in fact `()` with no commas.  Ami and I were simply discussing how it is different syntax than any other tuple, which requires a comma, even with one element. (I ultimately agree with Ami, btw. I just think it is less explicit.)

Comment: @JaimePerez If this answer solved your problem, feel free to accept it. It's how this site works.